# Memory Consumption of Jacobian Dataset Augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, cleverhans

I am trying to replicate results from https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02697, 
but using images size **224x224x3** following the black-box tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans_tutorials/mnist_blackbox.py

However, I am hitting a memory-consumption error (pasted below). It seems to me that jacobian dataset augmentation could be the source issue: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans/utils_tf.py#L657

Yet, I don't know how to check that.

I am running the code on 8GB GPU.

Could it be that this method can't work on bigger images? How can I fix this? What's the complexity of the method?

```
...
2019-02-07 18:21:32.984709: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:645] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 7.31GiB
2019-02-07 18:21:32.984715: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:647] Stats:
Limit:                  7860224000
InUse:                  7848987648
MaxInUse:               7848987648
NumAllocs:                10041921
MaxAllocSize:           2424832000

2019-02-07 18:21:32.984831: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] ****************************************************************************************************
2019-02-07 18:21:32.984849: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:199 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4,256,56,56] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely explained by the fact that the size of the `X_batch` doubles at each iteration `p_idxs`. If you replace L698-703 by a call to `batch_eval` provided in CleverHans, you will most likely be able to compute this even on ImageNet. If this solves your problem, feel free to submit as a PR to CleverHans on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to replace L698-703 with the call:

`grad_val = batch_eval(sess, [x], [tf.sign(grads)], [X_batch], batch_size=1)[0]`, but when I tested it against MNIST blackbox tutorial, I get an assertion error on output tensor:

`... line 481, in batch_eval
assert e.shape[0] == cur_batch_size, e.shape 
AssertionError: (10, 1, 28, 28, 1)`

Comment: Looks like you will have to squeeze out the dimension 1 (the second) before passing the data batch to the batch_eval method.

Comment: That `1` represents `batch_size` so I would assume it should stay. 28x28x1 represent WxHxC and the first dimension represents how many grads need to be computed (for every class, 1 grad is computed), i.e. `10` in this case. I believe this is what leads to a problem with age estimation task: computing grads for 101 class and 224x224 images require > 8gb RAM on GPU. That said, I think the solution is not that easy as replacing the sess.run() with batch.eval(), i.e. computing it in batches. Even if it would be, I am not sure how to pass it to batch_eval then. 

What do you think about this?

Comment: Now I reduced number of classes (from 100) to 4 and kept 224x224x3 images. Started augmentation of 1000 samples, but process got killed by kernel (due to resource exhaustion).